# Postgresql- Merge data from multiple tables only if

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for a way to Join two columns on Id. 
Table2 id has duplicate id. I need to filter Id where test has a minimum value and associated test2, but drop the rest. 
I am getting multiple ID along with test when I use INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN.

```
Sample data
Table1

        +----+--------+-----+
        | Id | weight | seq |
        +----+--------+-----+
        | 58 | 180    | 34  |
        +----+--------+-----+
        | 36 | 139    | 33  |
        +----+--------+-----+
        | 53 | 150    | 91  |
        +----+--------+-----+

Table2
+----+------+-------+
| Id | test | test2 |
+----+------+-------+
| 58 | 90   | 12    |
+----+------+-------+
| 36 | 45   | 19    |
+----+------+-------+
| 36 | 23   | 24    |
+----+------+-------+
| 53 | 20   | 22    |
+----+------+-------+
```

Desired output

```
+----+--------+-----+------+-------+
| Id | weight | seq | test | test2 |
+----+--------+-----+------+-------+
| 58 | 180    | 34  | 90   | 12    |
+----+--------+-----+------+-------+
| 36 | 139    | 33  | 23   | 24    |
+----+--------+-----+------+-------+
| 53 | 150    | 91  | 20   | 22    |
+----+--------+-----+------+-------+

 SELECT
    table1.id, 
    table1.weight, 
    table1.seq, 
    table2.id, 
    table2.test, 
    table2.test2
    FROM 
    public.table1
    LEFT JOIN public.table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.id;

SELECT 
table1.id, 
table1.weight, 
table1.seq, 
table2.id, 
table2.test, 
table2.test2
FROM 
public.table1
INNER JOIN public.table2 
ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

My output

```
+-----------------------------+
| ID Weight seq id test test2 |
+-----------------------------+
|   36  139   33  36  45   19 |
|   36  139   33  36  23   24 |
|   53  150   91  53  20   23 |
|   58  180   34  58  90   12 |
+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Please post have tried till now

Comment: please update it in your question

Comment: @Kul you can [edit] your question to add more information - it makes it easier to read than a series of comments

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `row_number()` window function to get the row with the minimal `test` value:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   (SELECT id, test, test2, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY test ASC) rk
        FROM   table2) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND rk = 1
```